# What is the necessity of having a shared instance of appDelegate?

Tags: swift

I found some come that I'm having trouble to understand

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

which is used in a "Loader" class

```
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let root = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootView")
   root.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   self.appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
   self.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = root
   self.appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

but the "same code" can be found in the "AppDelegate" class

```
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
           let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
           var vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RootView") // CHECK (???)
           self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
           self.window?.rootViewController = vc
           self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
           }
```

I've realized that it can be used to access the AppDelegate methods and variables from other classes, but I'm failing to grasp the potential of this approach and the reason it is implemented

Comment: You don't have a *shared instance of AppDelegate*, you have the instance of the application delegate class of the **shared application** instance. It makes perfect sense that the application itself is a singleton.

Comment: It's not that you have a shared instance of AppDelegate, iti's that you have only one `UIApplication`, a `shared` one (singleton pattern), and it has one delegate, the AppDelegate. Now, iOS prefers using "scenes", istead of usnig the "Application (delegate) window"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a single instance of the *application* running, that is an instance of `UIApplication`. And this application is assigned a delegate, which you implement. Since you can get the running application instance with `UIApplication.shared`, you can also query its delegate and you thus have a "singleton" of your application delegate as a by-product.

People often end up packing a lot of code into their app delegates since it can be conveniently queried everywhere in your app and it usually "knows" or has direct or indirect access to most pieces of the app.

Comment: Clear as a lighthouse in the dark. Much appreciated.